# Hyper-V Server not visible from Hyper-V Manager

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, windows-server-2012-r2

Through our technet subscription, I have downloaded and installed hyper-V Server 2012 R2.

I then have a Windows 8 server running Hyper-V Manager.

Both machines indicate that they belong to the "WORKGROUP" work group.

When I try to add the Hyper-V server in the manager program, it simply cannot find it and I do not have the option of connecting via IP address.

Is there a special way to enable the Hyper-V Server to be visible to a manager program?

Answer (score 0):

Please install the Hyper-V Management tools on Windows 8 in order to access Windows 2012 R2 remotely. Refer this [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn632582.aspx) link for further proceedings.